# Sequence-to-Sequence Model not performing well

Tags: keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, autoencoder, sequence-to-sequence

I am trying to build a seq2seq autoencoder that should have the ability to capture the logic of a sequence and be able to reconstruct it from the state vectors. I am using some example sequences to test if the model is capable of doing a very simple version of the task. I have sequences that go like '<><><>...' or '(.)(.)(.)...' for this purpose.

The basic code of the model looks like this:

```
n_hidden = 256
emb_dim = 16
n_tokens = 559

#Encoder
enc_inp = Input(shape=(None,))
emb_layer = Embedding(input_dim=n_tokens, output_dim=emb_dim)
enc_emb = emb_layer(enc_inp)
enc_layer = LSTM(n_hidden, return_state=True)
enc, state_h, state_c = enc_layer(enc_emb)

#Decoder
dec_inp = Input(shape=(None,))
dec_emb = emb_layer(dec_inp)
dec_layer = LSTM(n_hidden, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
dec, _, _ = dec_layer(dec_emb, initial_state=[state_h, state_c])
dense_layer = Dense(n_tokens, activation='softmax')
res = dense_layer(dec)

model = Model([enc_inp, dec_inp], res)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])


#Models for Inference

#Encoder
encoder_model = Model(enc_inp, [state_h, state_c])

#Decoder
state_inp1 = Input(shape=(n_hidden,))
state_inp2 = Input(shape=(n_hidden,))   
dec, state_h, state_c = dec_layer(dec_emb, initial_state=[state_inp1, state_inp2])
res = dense_layer(dec)

decoder_model = Model([dec_inp] + [state_inp1, state_inp2], [res] + [state_h, state_c])
```

The encoder inputs are the integer encoded characters that get turned into vectors by the embedding layer. The decoder input are the same as the encoder inputs but with a start token appended to the beginning and therefore shifted by one to the right. The results that are used in training are the one-hot encoded encoder inputs.

Now the model ist not performing really well but only predicting the first character over and over again, so for: 
Original: '<><><>...', Prediction: '<<<<<<...'
Original: '(.)(.)(.)...', Prediction:  '((((((...'

Is it just a question of training or is there some crucial mistake I am making here?

Comment: You can tune its hyperparameter such as `emb_dims`, `add more lstm` layer, `reduce` dims of `n_hidden`. There is no right solution for this, if your model is correct.

Comment: Hi @AnkishBansal, thanks for your reply. The thing is, I am not quite sure if the model is correct as adding more layers for example did not improve the results at all. This is why I am questioning it so much.